# Copy deployment items in Visual studio load test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I believe I need to copy data (settings files) to the deployment folder.  I write "believe" because I might be on the wrong track.  I also believe I want to decide what should be copied to the deployment folder in the load test (not unit test, project or solution).

Here is the situation:
I develop unit tests used in a load tests in one place.  I then copy the whole solution to the target site in the other end of the country.  Now some local settings have to be applied and as for now they are in a (source code) file.  This is obviously a bad solution as a pure copying of the solution also overwrites the locally updated file(s).

Now the load tests I do when developing the unit tests aren't the same as the ones used on the target site.  I am interested in speed of testing, debugging and short turn around times while the target site is interested in long running tests and measuring the outcome.

Alas I think that the load test files (.loadtest) are the right place for putting local settings.  But I find no place to enter a folder or files to copy to the deployment folder.
I have succeeded with copying data to the deployment folder through the [Test view] or [Test list editor] and properties but that is for every unit test class.  Well... I could probably mark all and update the Deployment items for every unit test class but that would require anyone writing a new test class to also update this property and I would prefer to have the settings in the load test and not in the unit test.

Comment: Perhaps creating a [LoadTest Plug-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243153.aspx) could be a solution. But then you have to write the code that deploys your file by your own.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you are interested in is controlled by a [testrunconfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182480%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) file, a solution item. You probably already have one called "LocalTestRun.testrunconfig". Create one specifically for load testing called something like "Remote.testrunconfig". Right click on it to set it as the active testrunconfig, then open it and add the files or folders you need to copy in the Deployment tab.

Comment: This mostly works, but I've run into a bit of a snap.  For a directory, it is taking the contents of any directory I specify and dumping its contents into the root of the Out folder.  What I want instead is to copy my specified directory itself below the out folder, not dump its contents.  I could hack this by nesting my source directory inside of itself, but I really don't want to have to do that, as it would affect other test projects that need that directory.  Any thoughts?